# Stop SFTP/FTP connection while the active connection is not transferring data in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, connection, timeout

I'm having an issue but I can't see something related with this.

I'm having an issue, something is happening while I'm performing an FTP connection with a server is transferring a file, but for some reason sometimes is stuck but I would like to prevent have the connection opened, there is a way to see if the FTP connection is not transferring, close the connection?

I really don't have any code due I'm not sure if this is possible,

Any idea what can I do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

If it is closing the connection while you are transferring files, then it's either your FTP/SFTP client, server, or network. First, Switch to a different FTP/SFTP client. Some have more tools for analysis than others. I have had to do this before. If that doesn't work, check the internet connection or contact your system/network administrator.

Comment: It's not closing the connection, connection remain opened, but for some reason it's stuck, probably while it's transferring something happened with the file and my script not continue and the connection still opened.

Comment: Ok, it sounds to me either the file itself is corrupted. If it's not, I would still try a different FTP/SFTP client. One time I was having the same problem as you. I was trying to send JPG's over a network, and even thought the network was still open, the files never transferred over. I changed my client, and solved the issue :)

Comment: I can't change it, I have to modify my script.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a way to see if the FTP connection is not transferring, close
>   the connection?

If you are downloading a file, you can indirectly see the FTP transferring by watching the file's size:

```
name=$1
size=0
while   sleep 10
        set -- `ls -s $name`
        [ "$1" -gt $size ]
do      size=$1
done
exit 1
```

The above script (let's call it `growing`) runs while the file (passed as a parameter) grows.
In your script you could write something like

```
growing file || pkill ftp &
```

before you start the FTP. If the file stops growing for ten seconds, `ftp` would be killed and the connection thereby closed. If ftp terminates normally, you could `kill $!` or just let `growing` end.